# django endless pagination making the second page to use different css in bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-endless-pagination

I am using django-endless-pagination with twitter style pagination and twitter bootstrap on my website.

Now, with django-endless-pagination, when the first page is displayed, system is using the below style.

```
    .row-fluid .offset1:first-child {
        margin-left: 8.547008547008547%;
     }
```

But from the second page onwards, the style used for the first element is as below.

```
    .row-fluid .offset1 {
        margin-left: 11.11111111111111%;
     }
```

As the margin-left is different for both pages first element, the rows are not aligned between page 1 and page 2. How do i change this, so that second page first element also uses first-child style and it is aligned.

Edit :-

My code looks like below in the template

```
    <div class="offset1 span10">

            <div class="span4">
                {% lazy_paginate column_1_items_list %}
                {% if column_1_items_list %}
                    {% for column_1_item in column_1_items_list %}
                        <div class="row-fluid image_div" style="padding-top:20px">
                            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="link">name_of_item</a></h4>
                             <a target="_blank" href="link_for_item">
                                <img class="item-size" src="photo.url" alt="name_of_item "/>
                            </a>
                            <p> quick_summary|safe </p>
                            <div class="row-fluid bottom">
                                <span class="price"><b>£ price</b></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {% show_more " " %}
            </div>
      </div>
```

Thanks
Sreekanth

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use `forloop.first` and add a class to your css.

```html
{% for column_1_item in column_1_items_list %}
    <div class="row-fluid image_div{% if forloop.first %} first_child{% endif %}" style="padding-top:20px">
    ...
{% endfor %}
```